# Send an adaptive microsoft teams webhook from ansible with a table that has a dynamic amount of rows

Tags: json, ansible

I want to create an adaptive card for MS Teams webhook. The data is coming from the result of a api call which is json. The data has 2 columns but dynamic amount of rows.

Below I have a template and playbook.

Template - adaptive_card_template.json.j2:

```
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Dynamic Table Example",
      "size": "Medium",
      "weight": "Bolder"
    },
    {
      "type": "Container",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": "Column 1",
          "weight": "Bolder"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": "Column 2",
          "weight": "Bolder"
        }
        {% raw %}
        {{ table_rows_placeholder }}
        {% endraw %}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Playbook - webhook.yml:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Get json from web api
      delegate_to: localhost
      uri:
        url: "web_url_website_api"
      method: GET
      headers:
        Content-Type: "application/json"
      register: json_data

    - name: Load template
      slurp:
        src: adaptive_card_template.json.j2
      register: adaptive_card_json

    - name: Replace table rows placeholder
      set_fact:
      adaptive_card_json: "{{ adaptive_card_json | combine({'body': adaptive_card_json['body'] | replace('{{ table_rows_placeholder }}', json_data)}) }}"

    - name: Send Adaptive Card to Teams Webhook
      uri:
        url: webhook_url
        method: POST
        body_format: json
        body: "{{ adaptive_card_json | to_json }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Error:

Create Adaptive Card JSON gives error: The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute